# Linear Algebra Done Right 8.5 $V$ is the direct sum of $nullT^{dimV}$ and $rangeT^{dimV}$ Proof

Tags: linear-algebra

> 8.5 $V$ is the direct sum of $nullT^{\dim V}$ and $range T^{\dim V}$
>
> Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$. Let $n=\dim V$. Then
>
> $V=nullT^n \oplus range T^n$

The book first proves $(null T^n)\cap(range T^n)={0}$. It's easy to understand.

However, the book then gives $\dim nullT^n + \dim rangeT^n = dimV$ directly from the Fundamental Theorem of Linear Maps(3.22). Why?

Comment: I figure it out. 1. $T^n \in \mathcal{L}(V)$, so we can apply the Fundamental Theorem of Linear Algebra. 2. $nullT^n \oplus rangeT^n$ is treated as a subspace of $V$, we only need to prove $\dim ($nullT^n \oplus rangeT^n$) = \dim V$. So the proof logic is reasonable.

Answer (score -1):

$\newcommand{\null}{\operatorname{null}} \newcommand{\range}{\operatorname{range}}$First, $\null T^n \cap \range T^n = \{0\}$ implies that$^\color{blue}1$ $\null T^n + \range T^n = \null T^n \oplus \range T^n$. Now, $\dim(\null T^n \oplus \range T^n) = \dim(\null T^n) + \dim(\range T^n)$$^\color{blue}2$, but the Fundamental Theorem of Linear Maps applied to $T^n$ also gives us $\dim V = \dim(\null T^n) + \dim(\range T^n)$. So, $\null T^n \oplus \range T^n$ is a subspace of $V$ with the same dimension, which means that they are the same.

---

$^\color{blue}1$If $W_1$ and $W_2$ are two subspaces of $V$, $W_1+W_2 = W_1 \oplus W_2$ if and only if $W_1 \cap W_2 = \{0\}$. Recall: we say that $W_1+W_2 = W_1 \oplus W_2$ if every $v \in W_1+W_2$ has a unique expression of the form $v=w_1+w_2$, with $w_i \in W_i$.

$^\color{blue}2$In general, $\dim(W_1+W_2) = \dim(W_1)+\dim(W_2)-\dim(W_1 \cap W_2)$, so, when $W_1+W_2 = W_1 \oplus W_2$ we have $\dim(W_1+W_2) = \dim(W_1)+\dim(W_2)$.